# How to mask a two shapes in windows universal 10

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to mask a rectangle with a ellipse. However i don't find any examples for windows universal 10 apps.

if possible i like it to be xaml only.

edit

Example:
[image]

the white cuts out out a portion of the rectangle.
Meaning any content in the white would by moving move behind the black rectangle.

thanks in advance.

Comment: searching for a library. but i find only for wpf and windows universal 8.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by masking a rectangle with an ellipse. Do you have a visual example? You probably don't need a library or anything that involved.

Comment: i edited my post to include an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer.

```
<Grid Name="current" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Path Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="4" Fill="Gray">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                        <LineSegment Point="0,-200"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="200,-200"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="200,-150"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="200,-50" Size="50,50"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="200,0"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,0"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="200,-200">
                        <LineSegment Point="400,-200"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="400,0"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="200,0"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="200,-50"/>
                        <ArcSegment Point="200,-150" Size="50,50"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="200,-200"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path> 
    </Grid>
```